# Set up a local postgres database in electron with knex

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, electron

My goal is to create a new postgres database and connect to it whenever my application is installed or run in development mode. I started with the following basic setup:

```
$ npm install --save knex pg pg-stream
$ knex init
```

this creates my local configuration. However, I have to create a database before being able to do anything, I have to create my database matching the config and the user for it.

```
$ createdb $NODE_ENV
```

This also requires postgres to be installed locally. I think there must be a better way to do this. How should this be done with electron?

Comment: did you find solutin for this